# How To write TestCase nunit test for keyPairValue

Tags: tdd, nunit, testcase, key-pair

I am looking for a way to pass keyValuePair into my test with TestCase

```
[TestCase<KeyValuePair<int,string>>(1,"XX")]
public void someTest(KeyValuePair<int,string> expectedkeyValuePairs)
{
    // do some thing;
}
```

The answer is

```
[TestCase(1,"XXX")]
public void someTest(int key,string value)
{
    var expectedkeyValuePairs = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(key, value);
    // do some thing;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use two separate parameters: One for key, one for value. And then create the KeyValuePair from them within your test.

Comment: I have tried  `[TestCase(1,"XXX")]` but seems , it did not like it .

Comment: What does "did not like it" mean?

Comment: It works fine now, I just write the comment when you did not write your second sentence . tanx

Comment: Did you also change the method's signature accordingly, i.e. to two parameters?

Comment: It'd be great if you could vote up the answer and mark it as a solution. Thanks :-)